# Is Java's Generic T object the equivalent of C's Opaque pointer?

Tags: java, c

I'm learning C. I usually program in Java. In attempting to translate the concepts of C into Java to understand them, I came across the notion of "Opaque Pointer" and thought it similar to the "T" in Java as in `<T> void someMethod(T opaquePointer)`. Please confirm my understanding and provide any nuances I may be overlooking.

Comment: No, they're not really the same thing.  A slightly better analogy would be that an opaque pointer is like a Java variable whose type is an interface.  But that's not quite right either.  Just treat it as an entirely new concept.

Comment: what about just object i.e. `void someMethod(Object opaquePointer)`

Comment: Yes, I guess so.